# Use button with callto link

Tags: acumatica

Origine message is :
I would like to optimize the code below because acumatica open a new window when the callto function is called.
I want to Just execute callto without open a New Windows ?

```
  [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Tel1",
  MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select,
  MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
  [PXButton(ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.World)]

  protected virtual IEnumerable tel1 (PXAdapter adapter)
  {
    string tel1="callto:06XXXXXXXX";        
    throw new PXException("Redirect4:"+string.Format(tel1));
    return adapter.Get();
  }
```

Update of the message :
I would like not have the about:blank in the picture below, but I would like have only the 3CXPhone windows.

[image]

Comment: I voted to close this question because no question is being asked. [ask]

Comment: Sorry, I update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I utilized the following code to add a button on AP301000 which redirects to 'callto:' opening whatever associated program you have set ( mine opened teams ) for web calling.

```
public class AAAPInvoiceEntry_Redirect : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
{
    public PXAction<APInvoice> AATel1;

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Tel1", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    public virtual IEnumerable aAtel1(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        string tel1 = "callto:06XXXXXXXX";
        throw new Exception("Redirect0:" + string.Format(tel1));
    }
}
```